# How to make all binary files (images) download using requests() and open()?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, web-scraping, download, python-requests

When I try to download a image from one url, the code works, but when I try another URL, it dosen't work.
This Doesn't Work. It only creates the filename.

```
# This Doesn't Work.
import requests
url = 'https://ryanspressurewashing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/metal-
roof-after-pressure-washing.jpg'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('image3.jpg', 'wb') as my_file:
# Read by 4KB chunks
    for byte_chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        my_file.write(byte_chunk)



#  This Works?

import requests
url = 'http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/files/kitten.jpg'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as my_file:
# Read by 4KB chunks
    for byte_chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        my_file.write(byte_chunk)
```

Comment: what means "This Doesn't Work." ? Do you get error message ? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have links to two different servers - they may have different security systems. One of them may block scripts/bots. Open downloaded `.jpg` in text editor (or hex editor) and you will see text with warning `"<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>"`.

Comment: The server that the one that doesn't work on is my hosting account. The one that does work(the kitten image) is out of a web scraping book. This works: urllib.request.urlretrieve(), but not the other code.

Comment: I run you code and I get `image3.jpg` with text inside. As I said: some servers have restricted secury system. They don't like scripts/bots because scripts/bots don't watch advertisements and servers don't get money for this. So they may check cookies, headers, etc. And different modules may use different headers, etc. SO `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`  may works because it uses different headers then `requests.get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different portals may have different security systems to block script/bots.

When you open `image3.jpg` in text editor you will see

```
<head>
<title>Not Acceptable!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Not Acceptable!</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on  this server. 
This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Some servers may need correct `headerse`, `cookies`, `session-id`, etc. to give access to data.

This portal needs correct header `user-agent`

```
import requests

url = 'https://ryanspressurewashing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/metal-roof-after-pressure-washing.jpg'

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'
}

r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)

with open('image3.jpg', 'wb') as my_file:
# Read by 4KB chunks
    for byte_chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        my_file.write(byte_chunk)
```

---

`requests` as default uses `user-agent: python-requests/2.21.0` so portals can easily recognize script and block it.

You can see this header using `https://httpbin.org/get`

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
print(r.text)
```

Result:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
  }, 
  "origin": "83.23.39.165, 83.23.39.165", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

See more functions on [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/)

Comment: It was the headers. Thanks for the help and the extra info. about httpbin.org. Good little tool.