# BadZipFile: File is not a zip file error in Jupyter notebook in python

Tags: python

How to solve the "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"  error?

```py
import pandas as pd             
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

# these are new 
import requests, io             
import zipfile as zf            
import shutil                    
import os                       

from census import Census 

import geopandas as gpd 
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon # also needed

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

print("")
print("**********************************************************************************")
print("Downloading Shape files")
print("")

cwd = os.getcwd()

county_url = "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_lakes.zip"
    
r = requests.get(county_url ) 

lake_shapefile = zf.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)) 

lake_shapefile.extractall(path = cwd + "\\shapefiles\\lake")

del r, lake_shapefile
```

Error:

```
**********************************************************************************
Downloading Shape files

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-34cf0e97a55d> in <module>
     10 r = requests.get(county_url )
     11 
---> 12 lake_shapefile = zf.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
     13 
     14 lake_shapefile.extractall(path = cwd + "\\shapefiles\\lake")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel)
   1223         try:
   1224             if mode == 'r':
-> 1225                 self._RealGetContents()
   1226             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1227                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1290             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1291         if not endrec:
-> 1292             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1293         if self.debug > 1:
   1294             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: are you sure the url is correct?

Comment: The error is correct. Your url `https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_lakes.zip` returns a 406 code with the `requests` module. It does download via a browser, so what's likely is that the server is misconfigured or something along those lines.

Comment: @jrd1 ,What can be wrong along the lines?any idea and how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like the server thinks you're a bot (due to the error being reported by mod_security from apache). This link appears to be promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070804/how-to-make-all-binary-files-images-download-using-requests-and-open

Comment: @jrd1 Sorry! I am not able to understand from the link given above.Can you please show me how to do it in this code if I have to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a header and stream the data back to you since Apache's **[mod_security returned a 406](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/406-not-acceptable)** (the server likely thinks that you're a bot or doing scraping as no user agent has been passed by default with `requests.get()`):

```
import os
import requests

# Let's spoof a common user-agent (e.g. Chrome 74 / Windows 10).
# Doing so will fool Apache into thinking that we're making a request
# via the Chrome web browser.
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_lakes.zip'
request = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)

# Use the url to determine the filename to save the data as.
# Finally, write out the streamed data as binary data.
zip_filename = os.path.basename(url)
with open(zip_filename, 'wb') as zfile:
    zfile.write(request.content)
```

At that point, you can introspect (or unzip) the file as normal - e.g. `unzip -l ne_10m_lakes.zip`.

[This link is invaluable in showing how to apply a custom user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070804/how-to-make-all-binary-files-images-download-using-requests-and-open). [And, here you can find documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) on applying user-agents with `requests.get()`.

Related, here you can find a list of user-agents: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome